# Dynamic variable in .bat files to create log according to current date

Tags: batch-file

I am SAS program user and i wrote following .bat file for task scheduling. I would like to export a log file with filename %date%_log.log. As i m new to writing .bat script (i would like to have date with format ddmmmyyyy)

For create a enviornment variable i think i can do the following

```
@echo off   
set ddmmyyyy=%date:=~4, 2%%date:=~7, 2%%date:=~10, 4%
set logfile= "C:\log\log_%ddmmyyyy%.log"
```

While i do not know how to put it in the -Log statement. Plus i prefer ddmmmyyyy format instead of ddmmyyyy format.

```
REM Reference
    REM commands split over multiple lines ^ 
    REM Commends in .bat file REM

"C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.3\sas.exe"^
 -CONFIG "C:\sasv9.cfg"^
 -AUTOEXEC "C:\AUTOEXEC.sas"^
 -SYSIN "C:\script.sas"^
 -LOG %logfile%
```

Comment: By mmm, do you mean the month abbreviation, like Jan for January?

Comment: Hi @dbenham Yes. For example 13JUL2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with dates is a pain with Windows batch. Your use of %DATE% is unreliable because it is locale specific. Even within the English speaking world, different Windows machines use various formats. So a batch script that works on your machine may not work on another.

You can use WMIC OS GET LOCALDATETIME to reliably get the timestamp in YYYYMMDDhhmmss.ssssss-zzz format. And you could use lookup values to convert the month number into month abbreviations.

For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "months= 01:Jan 02:Feb 03:Mar 04:Apr 05:May 06:Jun 07:Jul 08:Aug 09:Sep 10:Oct 11:Nov 12:Dec"
set "ts="
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined ts set "ts=%%A"
set "yyyy=%ts:~0,4%"
set "mm=%ts:~4,2%"
set "dd=%ts:~6,2%"
for /f %%A in ("!months:*%mm%:=!") do set "mon=%%A"
set "logfile=C:\log\log_%dd%%mon%%yyyy%.log"

"C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.3\sas.exe"^
 -CONFIG "C:\sasv9.cfg"^
 -AUTOEXEC "C:\AUTOEXEC.sas"^
 -SYSIN "C:\script.sas"^
 -LOG %logfile%
```

But I have a simpler suggestion. You could use my [GetTimestamp.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4847) utility. It is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Your solution could be as simple as

```
@echo off
setlocal
call GetTimestamp -f "C:\log\log_{dd}{mth}{yyyy}.log" -r logfile

"C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.3\sas.exe"^
 -CONFIG "C:\sasv9.cfg"^
 -AUTOEXEC "C:\AUTOEXEC.sas"^
 -SYSIN "C:\script.sas"^
 -LOG %logfile%
```

Note- I personally don't like DDMMMYYYY for use in file names because it does not sort chronologically. I prefer YYYYMMDD, or YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: as yyyymmdd easily confuse with yyyyddmm.